# Rewriting URI on nginx doesn't work when using variables

Tags: nginx, routes

I have this map set:

```
map $id $backend_host {
    default http://primary-host;
    1 http://primary-host;
    2 http://secondary-host;
}
```

And the following locations:

```
location / {
  set $id 1;
  proxy_pass $backend_host;
}

location /second/ {
  set $id 2;
  proxy_pass $backend_host/;
  rewrite ^/second(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

And when posting to `http://nginx-host/second/some/uri` I see that it falls within the second location clause, the URI is being rewritten but then it is proxied to the primary host instead of the secondary.

On the other hand, when I'm setting the second location like this:

```
location /second/ {
  proxy_pass http://secondary-host/;
  rewrite ^/second(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

That is, without using variables, it works just fine.

Couldn't find anything in the docs that explains that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
map $id $backend_host {
    default primary-host;
    1 primary-host;
    2 secondary-host;
}

location / {
  set $id 1;
  proxy_pass http://$backend_host;
}

location /second/ {
  set $id 2;
  proxy_pass http://$backend_host/;
  rewrite ^/second(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> or even like this:
>
> > proxy_pass $request;
>
> In this case, the server name is searched among
>   the described **server groups**, and, if not found, is determined using a
>   **resolver**.

Note: I did not test it